# C++ memory pool for a class and its derived classes

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

is there a common algorithm or implementation to have a memory pool that works both on a `class A` and its derived classes?
It is fairly easy to create a memory pool that works in O(1) only for a specific class A . For instance : allocate a big chunk of data, that is `10*sizeof(A)` and then give out 1à blocks of size `sizeof(A)` each time a allocation is needed.

Is there such a simple implementation when we can also consider the derived classes of A, that have a bigger size?
thanks

Comment: why do you need a concrete memory pool? can't you just store pointers and let the heap work for you?

Comment: it's just a theoretical question for practice on the operator new and operator delete...

Comment: The only approach I can think of that is not creating big management issues (for holes and whatever inside the memory chunk) is to use as the step size the size of the biggest class in the hierarchy tree. You won't waste much space if classes are not radically different.

Comment: There's a C++ rule that says to make non-leaf classes abstract. If you follow that rule, your situation can never arise in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what your definition of simple is.  As Jack said, you can use the size of largest of the derived classes as the element size of the array that is the memory pool.  That is definitely a simple implementation.

If some types were half the size of the largest type or smaller you could modify the implementation to allow a second instance to occupy a slot that is occupied a compatible instance.  That could be extended to quarter size types as well if applicable.